# How can I access the input on which datepicker is being applied

Tags: jquery, datepicker, this

I apply jquery datepicker to the input elements that has class `txt-date`:

```
 $('.txt-date').datepicker({
    showAnim: "blind",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    numberOfMonths: 2
});
```

As you can see I specified to show 2 months. But this is not the behavior I want with all input fields. To make it more flexible I'd like to determine the value of `numberOfMonths` property based on a custom attribute (something like `data-shown-months`) value. I tried to access the input element through `$(this)`, like this

```
<input type="text" class="txt-date" data-shown-months="2"/>

     $('.txt-date').datepicker({
    showAnim: "blind",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    numberOfMonths: $(this).data('shown-months')
});
```

but that didn't work. I tried `$(this).attr('data-shown-months')` too, to make sure it's not the problem with jquery `data` function. It seems `$(this)` refers to the datepicker itself. At least it doesn't refer to the source input element. Do you have any idea how I would access the source input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to whatever `this` is when you make the `datepicker()` call (probably `window`).  Placing `this` within an object parameter won't change its context.

Change to:

```
$('.txt-date').datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: $('.txt-date').data('shown-months') //"this" is probably window
});
```

If you had multiple elements with the "txt-date" class, each with its own "shown-months" value, you could initialize them all within an **[each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** loop.  In this case, `this` will point to each element:

```
$('.txt-date').each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: $(this).data('shown-months') //"this" is the current element
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @RIck. It really got it sorted out. Never thought `this` could refer to window.

Answer (score 1):

`this` always refers to the owner/caller of the running code. Since your code is running directly in the page, then the owner is the `window` object.

If you wrap your code in an event that belongs to your `input`, then `this` will refer to the `input` because it is the owner of the event:

```js
$('.txt-date').one("focusin", function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    showAnim: "blind",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    numberOfMonths: $(this).data("shown-months"),
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="txt-date" data-shown-months="1" value="1-month datepicker" />
<input type="text" class="txt-date" data-shown-months="2" value="2-months datepicker" />
```

The answer from Rick is obviously simpler, but I just wanted to explain how `this` works and how to use it to achieve what you wanted.